# Solve definite integral by parts, "one part at a time"

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

Suppose we have the following definite integral:

$$\int^a_b f(x)g'(x)dx$$

I know I can solve it using the *by parts* formula to obtain a primitive to then evaluate it in $a$ and subtract the evaluation of the same primitive in $b$.

I was wondering if the integral can also be solved using the *by parts* formula, calculate a primitive of the **second** integral (the one obtained applying the by parts formula) and calculating first the second integral in the $[a,b]$ interval and then recalculating the original integral, also in the $[a,b]$ interval of course.
In formulas:

$$\int^a_b f(x)g'(x)dx = f(x)g(x) - \int^a_b f'(x)g(x)dx$$

Then, calling the second integral $y(x) = \int^a_b f'(x)g(x)dx$ and being $Y(x)$ a primitive of the second integral, I wonder if is it ok to write:

$$ \int^a_b f(x)g'(x)dx = f(x)g(x) - \int^a_b f'(x)g(x)dx = [f(x)g(x) -  [Y(x)]^a_b]^a_b = [f(x)g(x) - (Y(a)-Y(b))]^a_b$$

We can then state $Y(a)-Y(b) = k$

$$[f(x)g(x) - (Y(a)-Y(b))]^a_b = [f(x)g(x) - k]^a_b = f(a)g(a)-k - (f(b)g(b)-k) = f(a)g(a)-f(b)g(b)$$

I'm asking this question because I tried to solve an integral both ways and I'm obtaining different results... What am I getting wrong here?

Comment: Just a little comment about wording: you should say "a primitive" and not "the primitive". This because there is not just one, but there are infinite primitives obtained by adding an arbitrary constant to any particular primitive you find. Also, the usual term used for primitive is "antiderivative"; I understood you because in my first language we call primitive what usually is called antiderivative as well.

Comment: Yes, you're right about the article, I'll edit it in a moment. I'm sorry, in all my courses (and a bunch of them were in engish language) we always called it "primitive"... So I just thought it was right =(

Answer (score 1):

let's consider this integral as firstly as an indefinte integral:

$\int_{}^{}f(x)g'(x)dx$

well this integral will be equal to :

$f(x)g(x)-\int_{}^{}(f'(x)g(x))dx$

if you considered the term $\int_{}^{}(f'(x)g(x))dx$ $=$ $z(x)$  then our original integral will be equal to $f(x)g(x)-z(x)$ and if you considered the definte integral from interval$[a,b]$ will be equal to :

$(f(x)g(x)-z(x))  |_{a}^{b}$

which is equal to : $(f(b)g(b)-z(b))-(f(a)g(a)-z(a))$

what you've written wrong that you've duplicated the term $z(x)$ which made it get cancelled

Answer (score -1):

> $$ \int^a_b f(x)g'(x)dx = f(x)g(x) - \int^a_b f'(x)g(x)dx $$$$= [f(x)g(x) -  [Y(x)]^a_b]^a_b = \mathbf{[f(x)g(x) - (Y(a)-Y(b))]^a_b} $$

is wrong. The correct thing should be $$ \int^a_b f(x)g'(x)dx = f(x)g(x)\Bigg |_b^a-\int^a_b f'(x)g(x)dx $$

EDIT: This is because $$ \int f(x)g'(x)dx= f(x)g(x) - \int f'(x)g(x)dx $$ so putting the limits we get $$ \int^a_b f(x)g'(x)dx = \left[f(x)g(x)- \int f'(x)g(x)dx \right]^a_b$$$$=(f(a)g(a)-f(b)g(b))-\int^a_b f'(x)g(x)dx $$$$= f(x)g(x)\Bigg |^a_b - \int^a_b f'(x)g(x)dx .$$

Comment: Sorry, could you explain me why? I can't see it

Comment: Your mistake is that over the second, f’(x)g(x) integral you have applied the limits of integration twice. See my edits, and if you still don’t understand, feel free to reach out.

Comment: I'm sorry but I still don't understand. Why you evaluated $f(x)g(x)$ from $b$ to $a$ when the integral was from $a$ to $b$? Let's suppose we have $\int^1_0 f(x) dx$, we calculate it as $F(1) - F(0)$, not as $F(0)-F(1)$ is it right? So why you wrote $f(b)g(b)-f(a)g(a)$?

Comment: I’m sorry . I messed up. Now after the new edit does it make sense?

Comment: Except of $f(x)g(x)\Bigg |_a^b$ (doesn't it has to be  $f(x)g(x)\Bigg |_b^a$ like the limits in the integral?) I think it's pretty clear. You're telling me I should have apply the limits of the integration a first time to $f(x)g(x)$, then find a primitive for $\int^a_b f'(x)g(x)dx$ and apply the limits of the integration to it as well... But still a single time and not twice. Did I get it right?

Comment: @ela Yes you got it right. And I fixed the typo.

Comment: Thank you very much! Could you also give me an intuitive rationale of why is it wrong to apply the limits of the integration twice?

Comment: Is this helpful? https://www.khanacademy.org/math/ap-calculus-bc/bc-integration-new/bc-6-11/v/integration-by-parts-of-definite-integral

Comment: Generally yes, I mean: it doesn't explain the problems of applying the limits of the integration more than one time, but explains how to calculate a defiite integral very good